Python singleton implementation not working
I am trying to implement a singleton pattern for a config class. I have a _Config class which loads the config.yaml file. Config class is a subclass of _Config class, whenever creating an instance of Config class, I expect it always returns the single instance. 
However the Config class does not work as expected. The error is shown at the end.
Can you please explain what is going on? Where are the errors coming from?
This the internal _Config class:
import yaml
from loguru import logger
import os


def _load_config() -> dict:
    logger.debug(f'Current work dir: {os.getcwd()}. Loading the config.yaml data...')
    filename = 'config.yaml'
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        try:
            return yaml.safe_load(f)
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            logger.critical(exc)
            # raise Exception(exc)
            raise


class _Config(dict):
    """This class is an internal class not to be accessed directly. Use `Config` class instead."""

    # def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

    def __init__(self, config: dict = None):
        """
        By default, the Config class is initialized with the `config.yaml` file at the root directory, unless a `config`
        parameter is provided.
        :param config: a config dictionary to be initialized
        """
        super().__init__()

        self._config: dict = config or _load_config()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == '_config':
            return self._config

        if name not in self._config:
            raise AttributeError(name)

        item = self._config.get(name)
        if item is None:
            raise NotImplementedError(f'"{name}" not found in config.yaml')
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            item = _Config(config=item)
        return item

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self.__getattr__(name)

The following is the Config class that should be used externally:
class Config(_Config):
    """
    The `Config` class for the configs with a singleton instance. This class wraps the `_Config` class. \n
    The reason to use a wrapper class to implement singleton pattern is that the class `_Config` itself cannot be
    implemented as a singleton class. This is because in its `__getattr__` method, the `_Config` class may need to be
    constructed:\n
    `item = _Config(config=item)`
    """
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        logger.debug('__new__')
        if cls._instance is None:
            logger.debug('Creating a new _Config instance')
            cls._instance = super(Config, cls).__new__(cls)
            #
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_config'):
            logger.debug('no _config')
            super().__init__()

However the code does not work. When running config1 = Config(), I got the following output:
2024-09-07 08:39:43.844 | DEBUG    | config:__new__:66 - __new__
2024-09-07 08:39:43.844 | DEBUG    | config:__new__:68 - Creating a new _Config instance


Ran 1 test in 0.158s

FAILED (errors=1)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/project/tests/test_config.py", line 22, in test_config
    config1 = Config()
              ^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/project/config.py", line 74, in __init__
    if not hasattr(self, '_config'):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/project/config.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    item = self._config.get(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/project/config.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    item = self._config.get(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/project/config.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    item = self._config.get(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  [Previous line repeated 2983 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded


why go through all this rigamarole?

@juanpa.arrivillaga The singleton pattern is in class Config(_Config). It's not much.

This error happens because of infinite recursion in your code.
When you initialize Config class config1 = Config() code trying to check existence of _config attr in your __init__, this happens, because hasattr calls __getattr__ under the hood. But in  __getattr__ you are calling __getattr__ again by self._config.get() and here we are, infinite recursion.
To fix this problem you could change Config.__init__ to following way:
class Config(_Config):
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        if '_config' not in self.__dict__:
            logger.debug('no _config')
            super().__init__()


When calling hasattr(self, '_config'), under the hood __getattr__ is called, but why it's reaching item = self._config.get(name)?  Shouldn't it reach if name == '_config' in my implementation and then return self._config already?
